# Como verificar se um número é decimal?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de saber se um número é decimal, ou seja, se contém "vírgula"?;

Um código que achei foi este:

**Html**

```
   <input type="text" onblur="isNumber(this.value)" id="text" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function isNumber(text){  
     valor = parseFloat(text);  
     if ((!isNaN(valor))==false){
        alert("Por favor, não digite ...");}  
     return true;  
  }
```

Via: http://scriptsexemplos.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/validar-se-um-numero-e-decimal.html

Porém não está dando resultado. Para ver como ficou clique [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/Lwf62/)

Para resumir, apenas quero uma condição que retorne

`true` para: `5.69541` e

`false` para: `569`.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se seu número está em formato texto, a maneira mais garantida de determinar se ele é ou não decimal é através de uma regex:

```
texto.match(/^-?\d+\.\d+$/);
```

Isso porque só usar `parseInt` e `parseFloat` não bastam - o texto pode **começar** com um número e conter outras coisas depois:

```
parseInt("123abc");     // 123
parseFloat("123.4abc"); // 123.4
```

Se o seu número já está em formato `Number`, por outro lado, pode-se determinar se ele é decimal calculando o resto da divisão por `1`:

```
x % 1 != 0 && !isNaN(x % 1) // true se e somente se x é decimal
```

Números inteiros sempre retornam zero como resto da divisão por 1, enquanto números fracionários retornam um valor diferente de zero. `NaN` e `Infinity` retornam `NaN`.

Comment: Sua última linha de código resolve o problema todo de um jeito mais elegante que a minha solução.

Comment: Uma coisa que nunca entendi até hoje são esses símbolos misturados (`/^-?\d+\.\d+$/`), que você chamou de regex. Pesquisarei e entenderei sua resposta @mgibsonbr. Mas parece ser ótima.

Comment: @SamirBraga Pesquise mesmo, pois expressões regulares (*regular expressions* - `RegExp` ou simplesmente regex) são uma ferramenta poderosa, ainda que muitas vezes mal utilizada. Minha expressão acima diz: `^` começo da string, `-?` com ou sem menos na frente, `\d+` um ou mais dígitos, `\.` ponto, `\d+` um ou mais dígitos, `$` fim da string.

Comment: E outra, sua solução com regex é bem mais rápida que a minha: http://jsperf.com/regex-versus-parseint-float-isnan. @SamirBraga, você devia aceitar esta resposta em vez da minha...

Comment: @bfavaretto No V8 (Chrome, Opera), sim, mas no Firefox e Safari a sua é mais rápida. Regex não costuma ser algo eficiente... Mas nesse caso, é necessário (o `parseFloat` sofre do problema do prefixo numérico e sufixo qualquer, como mencionado na resposta).

Comment: Eu gosto da solução com regex porque é bem mais simples. Eu precisei do `isNaN` para eliminar os sufixos que o parseInt/float deixam passar, e outros valores não numéricos.

Answer (score 10):

Se entendi bem, você quer uma função que retorne `false` para inteiros e valores não numéricos, e `true` para números quebrados.

Algo assim deve funcionar:

```
function isDecimal(num) {
    if(isNaN(num)) return false;             // false para não numéricos
    return parseInt(num) != parseFloat(num); // false para inteiros
}
```

Os números precisam ser passados com ponto como separador, não vírgula. Ah, e jogue fora o código que você achou na internet. É um lixo, tem pelo menos 2 problemas em 4 linhas... Pelo menos o dono do site admite que tem coisa ruim ali :)

---

Conforme pedido, o mesmo código reescrito usando chaves no `if`:

```
function isDecimal(num) {
    if(isNaN(num)) { return false; }
    return parseInt(num) != parseFloat(num);
}
```

Ou:

```
function isDecimal(num) {
    if(isNaN(num)) { 
        return false; 
    } else {
        return parseInt(num) != parseFloat(num);
    }
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
function isDecimal(num) {
    return (parseInt(num) != parseFloat(num)) && !isNaN(num);
}
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar o seu exemplo na estrutura simples do ´if´, ou seja, com chaves(`{ }`), para que eu consiga adequar ao meu caso. Desculpe meu desconhecimento, é que ainda estou começando.

Comment: Ok. Como você está começando, não deixe de fazer o que eu falei no comentário lá em cima: sempre teste seu código com o console do browser aberto (F12), mesmo no jsfiddle. Vários erros são mostrados em vermelho, e são informações fundamentais pra você postar quando for perguntar algo aqui no site.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição na sua resposta, pude testar com o meu exemplo, e constatei que seu código difere os números dos demais valores, como palavras, porém o mesmo retorna ´true´ tanto para números decimais(5.66, com ponto), quanto para números inteiros(566). Não os diferindo.

Comment: Tem certeza, @SamirBraga? Meus testes dão resultados diferentes http://jsfiddle.net/V52p4/

Comment: Agora com seu exemplo pude perceber que estava realizando a função de modo incorreto. Obrigado por sua resposta, verdadeiramente me ajudou.