# Como saber se o cálculo gerou um número inteiro?

Tags: javascript

Como saber se o cálculo gerou um número inteiro ?

exemplo: `if (10 / 2 = NUMERO INTEIRO) {}`

Comment: A resposta do Sergio é mais eficiente.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Como verificar se um número é decimal?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27919/215)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[<sub>**parseInt (referência)**</sub>](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
divisao = 10/2;
if( divisao === parseInt( divisao ) )
{    
    alert("10/2 resultou em inteiro")
}
else
{
    alert("10/2 não é um inteiro")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Outra alternativa à resposta correta do Papa Charlie é ver se o resto da divisão por 1 é zero.

Usando o operador `%`, e se o numero fôr inteiro, então dividir por 1 deve dar resto zero.

```
if ((10 / 2) % 1 == 0) { } // eu sou inteiro!
else { } // eu não sou inteiro!
```

Se fôr usar esta funcionalidade várias vezes pode fazer uma função para isto, por exemplo:

```
function inteiro(nr) {
    return nr % 1 == 0;
}
console.log(inteiro(10/2)); // true
console.log(inteiro(10/3)); // false
console.log(inteiro(10/4)); // false
console.log(inteiro(10/5)); // true
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/g45n0hek/