# Mostrar mensagem de aviso ao digitar valor numerico

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário que recebe um único valor. Quando o usuário digitar o valor `100.000` (cem mil) por exemplo, quero que ele carregue uma mensagem de aviso logo abaixo do input.

> "Valor a baixo do permitido".

```js
const ValorImovel = document.querySelectorAll("#ValorImovel")

function MontaAlerta(event) {
  // var numb = "100";
  if (event === 100) {
    console.log(event.value)
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", MontaAlerta)
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="centered-form">
    <div class="preco-item">
      <input id="ValorImovel" name="ValorImovel" class="form-control input-form" placeholder="R$ 0" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer restringir o valor a ser inserido a digamos `R$ 100,00` (ou qualquer outro valor), deve comparar o conteúdo do input com 100 (ou o valor desejado) e exibir o alerta. No caso abaixo, colquei um `span`com o id `alerta` que é preenchido com o `Valor inválido`.
Caso o valor seja maior do que `100`, o conteúdo do `span` é removido.

```js
const ValorImovel = document.querySelectorAll("#ValorImovel")

function MontaAlerta(event) {
  // var numb = "100";
  if (event.target.value <= 100) { //o valor atual é menor ou igual a 100?
    document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = 'Valor inválido'; //mostro o alerta
    console.log(event.target.value)
  } else { //valor acima de 100
    console.log('error')
    document.getElementById('alerta').innerHTML = ''; //limpo o alerta
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", MontaAlerta)
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="centered-form">
    <div class="preco-item">
      <div>
        <input id="ValorImovel" name="ValorImovel" class="form-control input-form" placeholder="R$ 0" type="text" />
      </div>
      <span id="alerta"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Lembre-se que neste caso, o único processamento é alertar que o valor é inválido, mas ainda assim, qualquer valor está sendo aceito, portanto, um processamento posterior deve ser feito.

Sugiro também, que use um `input` do tipo `number` com o atributo `min="100"` que irá instruir o navegador a restringir o intervalo de valores aceitos conforme o exemplo:

```html
<form>
  <div class="centered-form">
    <div class="preco-item">
      <div>
        <input id="ValorImovel" name="ValorImovel" class="form-control input-form" placeholder="R$ 0" type="number" min="100"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

No caso acima, o próprio navegador irá se encarregar de recusar valores menors do que `100`, a desvantagem, é que o feedback só irá existir na hora da submissão, mas você pode combinar com o evento de `keyup`.

Comment: PERFEITO, funcionou e pude compreender muito bem, muitíssimo obrigado! :D

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar. Lembre-se de sempre aceitar as respostas. Até mais.

Comment: Só um detalhe., esse input deveria ser do tipo _number_ pra evitar de passar algo que não seja número.

Comment: entendido, mais uma vez obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro equivoco esta na primeira linha:

```
const ValorImovel = document.querySelectorAll("#ValorImovel")
```

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) retorna lista de elementos presentes no documento que coincidam com o grupo de seletores especificado.
Ou seja, sua variável `ValorImovel` é uma referência para um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList) e não para o elemento desejado. Se quer encontrar a referência a um elemento pelo seu `id` use o método [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Nessa linha:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", MontaAlerta)
```

Você define como alvo o objeto [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window) representa a janela, o que implica que esse listener escutará todos os eventos `keyup` disparados e caso adicione outros inputs ao seu código seria bem trabalhoso distinguir e trabalhar quem disparou o evento.
Portando defina o ouvinte de eventos diretamente no alvo do evento.

A definição da função `MontaAlerta()` parece desnecessária pois claramente tem a finalidade de tratar um evento então pode ser reescrita como um [expressão de função](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) ao definir o ouvinte do evento `keyup`.

Outra coisa que falta é [verificar se o valor do input é decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27919/como-verificar-se-um-n%C3%BAmero-%C3%A9-decimal) valido.

Também falta cumprir com o requisito *uma mensagem de aviso logo abaixo do input* que um estilo com pseudo elemento [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after) bem posicionado pode cumprir.

```js
const ValorImovel = document.getElementById("ValorImovel")

ValorImovel.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (!this.value.match(/^-?\d+(.\d*)?$/)) {
    this.parentElement.classList.add("errado");
    return;
  } else {
    this.parentElement.classList.remove("errado");
  }
  if (parseFloat(this.value) < 100) {
    this.parentElement.classList.add("abaixo");
  } else {
    this.parentElement.classList.remove("abaixo");
  }
});
```

```css
.abaixo::after {
  display: block;
  content: "Valor a baixo do permitido";
  color: orange;
}

.errado::after {
  display: block;
  content: "#ERRO: Valor inválido!";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="centered-form">
    <div class="preco-item">
      <input id="ValorImovel" name="ValorImovel" class="form-control input-form" placeholder="R$ 0" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @SkywalkerJr você quer o código pronto? Ja foram propostas várias solucoes aqui e voce ainda quer mais o que? se tem outra dúvida, poste outra pergunta, as solucoes aqui já resolvem o problema especificado na pergunta....

Answer (score -3):

Dentro da funcao use: "event.target.value" para obter o valor do input;

ex:

```
function MontaAlerta(event) {
// var numb = "100";
if (event.target.value === 100) {
 console.log(event.target.value)
} else {
 console.log('error')
}
```

Comment: Opa, entao..
eu havia tentado, no entanto ele sempre entra no else e imprime 'error'.